# Распределение элементов по трем кучам с минимальной разницей

Tags: c#, алгоритм

> Необходимо достичь минимальной возможной разницы между суммами значений элементов в кучках

Вот то, что получилось у меня, ***Принцип работы*** - запихивание элемента в наименьшую кучку:

```
int item0 = 0, item1 = 0, item2 = 0; //Кучки
        List<int> templist = new List<int>() { 20, 19, 14, 13, 11, 9, 6 };
        foreach (var item in templist)
        {
            if (item0 <= item1 && item0 <= item2)
            {
                item0 += item;
            }
            else if(item1 <= item0 && item1 <= item2)
            {
                item1 += item;
            }
            else
            {
                item2 += item;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Первая кучка: " + item0);
        Console.WriteLine("Вторая кучка: " + item1);
        Console.WriteLine("Третья кучка: " + item2);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Код работает быстро, но точность не полная, он выводит:[image: Вывод моего кода]
А самый оптимальный вариант - 29, 31, 32. Это достигается путем таких сложений:
**29 = 20 + 9

31 = 14 + 6 + 11

32 = 19 + 13**

---

Как можно добиться такого результата?
***P.S.*** количество элементов списка может меняться, их значение тоже.
***P.P.S*** Список по умолчанию дается не сортированным, сделаем вид, что механизм сортировки в данное коде есть, но опущен.

Comment: *Вот то, что смог надумать:* Вообще-то главное - не код, который "надумался", а алгоритм, который в нём реализуется. А описания этого алгоритма мы в твоём вопросе что-то не видим...

Comment: @Akina исправлено

Comment: Это "Жадный алгоритм" называется. Он никогда не гарантирует оптимальности решения, хотя как правило даёт решение, близкое к оптимальному. Тут нужно менять именно алгоритм. Это - типовая задача о равномерном распределении (чисел, ресурсов,  вероятностей или ещё чего). Посмотрите теорию, выберите алгоритм из возможных - и реализуйте.

Comment: можно высчитать средний вес "идеальной" кучки (92/3 = 31, т.к. у нас вынужденно только целочисленные варианты решения и это ближайшее целое) и сперва попытаться её максимально точно собрать (что *в данном случае случайно* возможно); затем оставшиеся 2 пробовать собрать "как получиться поровну", причём если они будут равны, то они автоматически получаются "идеальными". Тогда на этом наборе вначале получится "идеальная" кучка 31=(14+6+11), затем 32=(19+13) как наиболее близкая к "идеальному" значению, а всё оставшееся будет 29=(20+9).

Comment: Итого, задачка упрощается до поиска алгоритма сбора одной кучки, сумма элементов которой д.быть максимально близка заданному значению; далее этот алгоритм применить N=3 раз.

Comment: @Alias Алгоритм ошибочен. Пример: исходный массив (7 10 10 11 11 11), сумма 60, среднее 20, по указанному алгоритму собираем первую кучку (10 10), точно равную среднему, после чего получаем для оставшихся элементов наборы (7 11) и (11 11), суммы соответственно 20, 18, 22, разброс 4, что не соответствует правильному ответу - группы (7 11), (10 11), (10 11), суммы 18, 21, 21, разброс 3.

Comment: @Akina действительно; жаль, это выглядело просто :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавлю немножко динамики.

```
public Tuple<int, int, int, int> FindMin(int[] numbers, Tuple<int, int, int, int> currentMin, int curIndex, int store1, int store2, int store3)
{
    if (curIndex == numbers.Length)
    {
        var minStore = store1 <= store2 && store1 <= store3 ? store1 : store2 <= store3 ? store2 : store3;
        var maxStore = store1 >= store2 && store1 >= store3 ? store1 : store2 >= store3 ? store2 : store3;
        var diff = maxStore - minStore;

        if (currentMin == null) return Tuple.Create(store1, store2, store3, diff);
        if (currentMin.Item4 <= diff) return currentMin;
        return Tuple.Create(store1, store2, store3, diff); ;
    }

    var curItem = numbers[curIndex];
    var comb1 = FindMin(numbers, currentMin, curIndex + 1, store1 + curItem, store2, store3);
    var comb2 = FindMin(numbers, currentMin, curIndex + 1, store1, store2 + curItem, store3);
    var comb3 = FindMin(numbers, currentMin, curIndex + 1, store1, store2, store3 + curItem);

    var min = comb1.Item4 <= comb2.Item4 && comb1.Item4 <= comb3.Item4 ? comb1 : comb2.Item4 <= comb3.Item4 ? comb2 : comb3;
    return min;
}
```

Воспользоваться можно так

```
var numbers = new[]{ 20, 19, 14, 13, 11, 9, 6 };
var min = FindMin(numbers, null, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine($"{min.Item1} {min.Item2} {min.Item3}");
```

Вывод

```
31 32 29
```

Кстати, если хранить дополнительные промежуточные показатели, типа максимум/минимум в текущей мин комбинации, то можно некоторые комбинации отсекать и не выполнять полный перебор.

Например, если хранить максимум в мин комбинации, и также задать начальную комбинацию близкую к решению, то можно сэкономить на переборе и времени работы. Как пример (за корректность не ручаюсь, но надеюсь :)):

Получим начальную комбинацию вашим алгоритмом

```
public Tuple<int, int, int ,int , int> GetStart(int[] numbers)
{
    int item0 = 0, item1 = 0, item2 = 0; //Кучки
    foreach (var item in numbers)
    {
        if (item0 <= item1 && item0 <= item2)
        {
            item0 += item;
        }
        else if (item1 <= item0 && item1 <= item2)
        {
            item1 += item;
        }
        else
        {
            item2 += item;
        }
    }

    var min = Math.Min(item0, Math.Min(item1, item2));
    var max = Math.Max(item0, Math.Max(item1, item2));
    return Tuple.Create(item0, item1, item2, max - min, max);
}
```

Улучшить эту стартовую комбинацию - означает уменьшить максимум в комбинации или увеличить минимум. Не думаю, что будет существовать более подходящая комбинация с увеличенным максимумом. Как это использовать? Проверять максимум в переборе

```
public Tuple<int, int, int, int, int> FindMin(int[] numbers, Tuple<int, int, int, int, int> currentMin, int curIndex, int store1, int store2, int store3)
{   
    if (curIndex == numbers.Length)
    {
        var minStore = store1 <= store2 && store1 <= store3 ? store1 : store2 <= store3 ? store2 : store3;
        var maxStore = store1 >= store2 && store1 >= store3 ? store1 : store2 >= store3 ? store2 : store3;
        var diff = maxStore - minStore;

        if (currentMin.Item4 <= diff) return currentMin;
        return Tuple.Create(store1, store2, store3, diff, maxStore); ;
    }

    // проверка максимума. Если ткущий максимум больше найденного, то дальше перебирать смысла нет, так как что бы не нашли, оно будет хуже уже найденного решения. 
    if (store1 > currentMin.Item5 || store2 > currentMin.Item5 || store3 > currentMin.Item5) return currentMin;

    var curItem = numbers[curIndex];
    var comb1 = FindMin(numbers, currentMin, curIndex + 1, store1 + curItem, store2, store3);
    var comb2 = FindMin(numbers, currentMin, curIndex + 1, store1, store2 + curItem, store3);
    var comb3 = FindMin(numbers, currentMin, curIndex + 1, store1, store2, store3 + curItem);

    var min = comb1.Item4 <= comb2.Item4 && comb1.Item4 <= comb3.Item4 ? comb1 : comb2.Item4 <= comb3.Item4 ? comb2 : comb3;
    return min;
}
```

Как использовать:

```
var numbers = new[] { 20, 19, 14, 13, 11, 9, 6 };
var start = GetStart(numbers);
var min = FindMin(numbers, start, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine($"{min.Item1} {min.Item2} {min.Item3}");
```

Вывод аналогичен

```
31 32 29
```

В итоге, вместо 3820 итераций в первом варианте, мы получим 499 итераций. То есть на предоставленных данных ускорение будет примерно в 7 раз.

Answer (score 4):

Гарантированно лучший вариант можно находить только полным перебором всех подмножеств. 
[Википедия (Задача разбиения множества чисел)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)

Comment: Заведомо неверное утверждение.

Comment: Конкретно в данном случае может и нет, но в общем случае - это задача разбиения множества чисел. Ссылку оставил

Comment: По поводу полного перебора всех подмножеств - поглядите мой ответ, я там выложил вариант где не обязательно перебирать все варианты (на предоставленных данных). Там перебор примерно 14% от всех подмножеств

Answer (score 2):

Полный перебор в функциональном стиле:

```
int[] numbers = { 20, 19, 14, 13, 11, 9, 6 };
int pilesNumber = 3;
int sum = numbers.Sum();
int combNumber = numbers.Aggregate(1, (m, number) => m * pilesNumber);
var perfectCombination =
    Enumerable.Range(0, combNumber)
              .Select(x =>
              {
                  var piles =
                      Enumerable.Range(0, pilesNumber)
                                .Select(y => new List<int>(numbers.Length))
                                .ToArray();
                  foreach (var n in numbers)
                  {
                      piles[x % pilesNumber].Add(n);
                      x /= pilesNumber;
                  }
                  return piles;
              })
              .MinBy(piles => piles.Sum(pile => Math.Abs(pile.Sum() * pilesNumber - sum)));
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("\n",
        perfectCombination.Select(
            list => list.Sum() + "=" + string.Join("+", list))));
```

Вывод:

```
29=14+9+6
31=20+11
32=19+13
```

Здесь `MinBy` из [пакета `Morelinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), подключите его или просто скопируйте к себе в проект исходный код [отсюда](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs)

Comment: не могли вы внести пояснение в данном функциональном подходе? Почему количество комбинаций будет перемножение всех чисел исходного массива?

Comment: Не всех чисел, а 3^N, где N - число элементов в массиве. Вычисляем количество комбинаций, запускаем цикл с 0 по (количество комбинаций - 1), для каждого этого числа (x) переводим его в троичную систему счисления, получится N-значное число, смотрим какая цифра в каждом разряде, если 0 - помещаем это число в первую кучку, если 1 - во вторую и т.д. Потом берем все возможные разбиения по кучкам и выбираем из них ту, в которой ошибка наименьшая.