# Перебор сумм времени операций для каждого оператора, которые будут максимально близки к заданному значению

Tags: алгоритм, время, линейная-алгебра

**Есть данные, где описаны операции по некоторому  общему процессу , которые делают несколько человек и указано время этих операций. Складывается время для нахождения общего времени выполнения процесса, указывается кол-во человек которые будут будут делать эти операции, и общее время делится на кол-во человек. Это будет таргетное время**

*Например:
Есть 10 операций и в сумме они делаются 180 минут. Их будут выполнять 2    человека.
Соответственно в сумме для каждого человека таргетное время должно быть примерно 90 мин.*

**Надо распределить операции так, чтобы они для каждого человека  в сумме давали максимальное близкое время к таргетному. Операции не должны повторяться.**

Операции имеют разнообразное время.

*Например:
Есть 7 операций по 5 минут и одна 40 минут. Одному человеку дадут 7 быстрых операций, а другому одну , но долгую, чтобы время у них было примерно равно.*

Данные по операциям и кол-ву человек, которые будут выполнять их, будет вводить пользователь. Поэтому решение должно быть универсальным.

Реализовывать надо в Excel( с помощью формул или макросов). Но мне главное сейчас понять логику этого решения!

Я думаю об инструменте "Подбор решения", но тут сложность в том, что кол-во слагаемых будет подбираемой величиной для каждого оператора.

Как выстроить логику решения?
Если есть какие-нибудь математические формулы или методы, тоже хорошо.

Comment: как `Подбор решения` поможет распределить задачи?

Comment: я бы начал с банального перебора. Вот тут [есть пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824938/179763) с 3 рабониками, но у вас количество работников будет заранее неизвестно.

Comment: Для двух человек динамическим программированием можно решить ([subset sum problem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144007/)), для трёх 
tym32167 показал возможность определённой оптимизации, для большего количества задача весьма сложна - задача о распределении камней по ящикам,  [пример эвристического поиска решения](https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/stones_in_boxes.html)