# Как разделить набор на 2 максимально равных части?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

> У вас есть несколько камней известного веса. Напишите программу, которая распределит камни в две кучи так, что разность весов этих двух куч будет минимальной.

Как решить? Мне не нужен код, нужен алгоритм.

Comment: возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274797/Задача-о-куче-камней-Перебор

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @tohatsu, там задача более сложная. И всё равно нет решения. Я не думаю что в таком случае можно говорить про дубликат.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5_0-1, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0+%D0%BE+%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Веса камней целые? Какие ограничения на веса и количество камней?

Comment: Поскольку мне просто лень переписывать 7 страниц текста :), замечу просто, что это задача оптимизации, связанная с NP-полной **задачей о сумме подмножества**, и решается точно сия задача только за экспоненциальное время; имеется также приближенное полиномиальное решение. См. Кормен и др., "*[Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ. 3 изд.](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html)*", раздел 35.5, стр. 1180-1186.

Comment: Дубликат? [Распределение элементов по трем кучам с минимальной разницей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824662/179763)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постоянно добавляем в меньшую по весу кучу самый тяжелый камень.

Вот собственно и есть весь алгоритм.

Comment: Ваш алгоритм `(8, 7, 5, 5, 5)` разделит на `(8, 5)`, `(7, 5, 5)`. А правильный ответ `(8, 7)`, `(5, 5, 5)`.

Comment: Если нет ограничений на веса, то полный перебор всех подмножеств и поиск лучшего варианта. Можно оптимизировать (метод ветвей и границ). Если веса небольшие целые, то есть решение быстрее - динамическое программирование. Так или иначе - задача известная и решена сотней способов, но все решения не очень простые. :)

Comment: Давайте перейдем на следующий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433746/Алгоритм-распределения-элементов

Answer (score 2):

1. Сортируем камни по весу в обратном порядке
2. Далее в цикле по отсортированным камням кладём камень в ту кучу, вес которой на текущий момент минимален.

Пример

камни: 5, 56, 45, 48, 12, 55, 15

1. Сортировка - 56, 55, 48, 45, 15, 12
2. Цикл приведёт к такому варианту:

### 56, 45, 15

### 55, 48, 12

разница - 1 кг

Comment: Ваш алгоритм `(8, 7, 5, 5, 5)` разделит на `(8, 5)`, `(7, 5, 5)`. А правильный ответ `(8, 7)`, `(5, 5, 5)`.

Comment: Действительно... Ну тогда можно добавить вторую итерацию прогона:
    `1. Запомнили разницу кучек
    2. Идём в цикле по кучке большего веса в обратном порядке: Если разница текущего камня итерации и самого лёгкого камня меньшей кучки больше или равна половине разницы кучек, то: 
      а. меняем элементы местами.
      б. возвращаемся в пункт 1.`

Перед этим, надо проверить - достаточно ли существенна разница в весе кучек, чтобы эта итерация имела смысл. Возможно, достаточно будет условия, что разница кучек больше, чем половина самого лёгкого камня.

Comment: Вы придумываете эвристики, которые иногда могут помочь. Но это известная задача - [задача о рюкзаке 0-1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5_0-1). Известный факт - для любого набора эвристик можно подобрать веса так что задача решается только полным перебором почти всех подмножеств.

Comment: "Эвристики", "иногда". Предлагаемая мной вторая итерация решает вопрос? Если нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, ситуацию когда результат будет плох. Если таковой не находится, мой вариант - рабочий алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из решений нашла в [задачнике](https://okpython.net/python/python_zadachnik/python_zadachnik.html) на https://okpython.net. Выглядит как-то просто, но для 5 камней с весом до 10 на первый взгляд выдает правильные ответы. Логика решения задачи только не совсем понятна.

```
# Импортируем time.
import time
# Начало выполнения программы.
start = time.time()

# Ииспользуем возможности модуля random.
from random import choice, choices

# Генерируем случайное количество камней.
n = choice(range(1, 101))
# Генерируем случайные веса камней.
w_li = choices(range(1, 1000000), k=n)
# Сортируем список по возрастанию весов.
w_li.sort()

# Начальные веса наших куч.
w_1 = 0; w_2 = 0

# Если камней четное количество.
if n%2 == 0:
    # Остаточный вес примем за нуль.
    w_min = 0
else:
    # Удалим из списка минимальный вес, 
    # чтобы осталось четное число элементов,
    # и сохраним его в переменной.
    w_min = w_li.pop(0)    

# Текущий флаг. 
f = 0     
# Пока список не станет пустым.
while w_li:
    # Распределяем по два соседних камня
    # по кучам, добавляя в одну и ту же 
    # кучу сперва камень с максимальным весом, 
    # а затем с минимальным из двух.
    if f == 0:    
        w_1 += w_li.pop()    
        w_2 += w_li.pop()
        f = 1
    else:
        w_2 += w_li.pop()    
        w_1 += w_li.pop()
        f = 0      

# Последний камень добавляем в кучу с минимальным весом.
if w_2 > w_1:
    w_1 += w_min
else: 
    w_2 += w_min

# Выводим минимальную разность весов.
print(abs(w_2 - w_1))
# Время выполнения программы.
print('Выполнено за', time.time() - start, 'сек.')
```